# How can I recover my home folder and log in again after accidentally moving in into "lost+found"?

Tags: login, data-recovery, delete, restore, home-directory

I use ubuntu 12.04.

I just curiously transferred 'my-username' folder into "lost+found" folder (which is normally locked), so that anyone from other user account can not access my files.

But, after restart I just can't log in to my account. I have lots of important files and software installed. What can I do now?

Is there any way to recover my home folder from the "lost+found" folder?

Comment: I made a few edits to clean up the question, hope it's an improvement

Comment: That's not what the `lost+found` folder is for: instead, it is a special folder where the file system checker will put files that exist on the disk but are not part of any other folder due to corruption.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to boot from a Live CD and un-do the action you took before by accessing your hard drive from the Live CD.  If you find that any important files are lost, you'll probably need to restore them from backup.

For future reference, you should never move/remove your home directory, and the "lost+found" folder on a partition is not for normal use and you shouldn't use it for file storage.

If you want to hide stuff in your home directory from other users, you change its permissions - you don't move it outside of your home directory.

I'd suggest to change your home directory's permissions to 771 - just that directory, not recursively.  That will still allow, for example, the login manager to access your wallpaper, but people will not be able to see a list of files in there.  If you want it to be even more hidden (so someone cannot see anything in there even if they know the directory/file name), use permission 770.

Keep a record of what you did and what it was previously.